# does jenkins shared library groovy class support groovy trait

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

i have a shared library with a simple class that implement a simple trait,

> HelloTrait.groovy :

```
package my.package

trait HelloTrait
{
  String sayHi()
  {
    return "Hi!"
  }
}
```

> Test.groovy:

```
package my.package

class Test implements Hellotrait
{
}
```

> jenkinsfile:

```
import my.package.Test

Test test = new Test();
echo test.sayHi();
```

but when running the pipeline jenkins throws an error
unsupported array expression